# Postgres logical replication subsynccommit off

Tags: postgresql, replication, logical-replication

I've got postgres 13 version and I've tuned logical replication from another
server.
I started replication, my tables are full of data. But when I add data on
publisher it is not added on replica. Logs are empty.
I've queryed
report=# select * from pg_subscription;

```
  oid  | subdbid | subname  | subowner | subenabled | | subslotname | subsynccommit | subpublications
-------+---------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------
 40498 |   23356 | lib1     |       10 | t          | | lib1        | off           | {rdwh_dev}
 46357 |   23356 | core1    |       10 | t          | | core1       | off           | {rdwh_dev}
```

its not wright that subsynccommit is off? Yes? Has it ti be on?

Can you give an advice?

Comment: unrelated.  Are you sure you are looking in the right place for the logs?  They are never empty.

Comment: You are wright, I was looking not in proper place. But logs were fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
As I've changed columns in publication, I had
to refresh the publication. When I did:

```
Alter subscription XXX refresh publication;
```

Everything started in normal way.
Disabling and enabling subscription didn't help.
Only refreshing